# How to make multiple batches consistent?

Tags: consistency

What do you think would be the best way to try and make 3 5-gallon batches and have them as consistent as possible? I am brewing for a party and want all 3 kegs to be so similar that you wouldn't be able to tell that they weren't a single batch.

Comment: you could do 3 different beers! A stout, an IPA and a blonde beer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Blend them all together as they go into the kegs.  1/3 of each carboy for 3 kegs.

Comment: Be sure to taste all the beer before mixing - of one batch has gone bad you'll end up with 15 gallons of bad beer, rather than just 5.

Comment: Hey now, he _was_ going for consistency. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say whether you intend to make them serially or consecutively (edit: oops, I meant concurrently). If you can't make one 15-gallon batch, or blend all three batches together after they're done (very gently, and without unduly exposing them to air) before kegging, temperature control is probably where you want to concentrate. I suggest you keep them all in the same room or the same cupboard—we do what we can, right?—and at the same temperature.

Comment: you are correct, I should have stated that. I do plan to make them all on the same day, but with the answer above, I could conceivably make them on 3 different days, and then mix. of course I wouldnt want too much time to elapse betwen batches :)